# App freezes when clicking checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have simply tried everything..
What my code does is taking information from the user and upload them to the database..
so the error states:

`05-12 12:20:19.721: E/AndroidRuntime(688): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCheckboxClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.senior.Userfilter for onClick handler on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'checkbox_secondhand'`

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.senior.Userfilter.postmanager;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
public class Userfilter extends BaseActivity{
ListView listview;
ListView c1;
ListView c2;
ListView c3;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3;
List<String> list;  
List<String> list1;
List<String> list2;
List<String> list3;
String Scategory;
String Pcolor;
String Scolor;
String Tcolor;
String userID="1";
ListView category;
EditText minprice;
EditText maxprice;
ListView color1;
ListView color2;
ListView color3;
EditText processtime;
EditText delivertime;
EditText feedrate;
EditText sellerrate;
CheckBox onSale;
CheckBox newitem;
CheckBox secondhand;
int Ionsale;
int Inew;
int Isecondhand;
int process;
int delivery;
int feed;
int seller;


String Smin;
String Smax;

Button submit;
PostParser jsonParser = new PostParser();
static String IP="172.29.16.195";
static String url1="http://"+IP+":80/Senior/filter.php";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter);
        System.out.println("in create");
        processtime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.process);
        delivertime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delivery);
        feedrate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feedback);
        sellerrate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.seller);
        onSale = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_onsale);
        newitem = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_new);
        secondhand = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_secondhand);
        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.filterlistview);
        c1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.color1);
        c2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.color2);
        c3=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.color3);
        list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("TV");
        list.add("Pens");
        list.add("Tablets");
        list.add("Tables");
        list.add("Phones");
        list.add("Books");
        list.add("Washing Machine");
        list.add("Phones");
        list1=new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add("Red");
        list1.add("Yellow");
        list1.add("Blue");
        list1.add("Green");
        list2=new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("Red");
        list2.add("Yellow");
        list2.add("Blue");
        list2.add("Green");
        list3=new ArrayList<String>();
        list3.add("Red");
        list3.add("Yellow");
        list3.add("Blue");
        list3.add("Green");
        category=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.filterlistview);
        minprice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.min);
        maxprice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.max);
        color1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.color1);
        color2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.color2);
        color3=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.color3);     
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public int onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
                // Is the view now checked?
                boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

                // Check which checkbox was clicked
                switch(view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.checkbox_new:
                        if (checked)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                case R.id.checkbox_onsale:
                        if (checked)
                            return 1;
                        else
                           return 0;
                case R.id.checkbox_secondhand:
                        if (checked)
                           return 1;
                        else
                           return 0;
                }
                return 0;
            }   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Smin=minprice.getText().toString();
                Smax=maxprice.getText().toString();
                Ionsale = onSale.getId();
                Inew = newitem.getId();
                Isecondhand = secondhand.getId();
                process=Integer.parseInt(processtime.getText().toString());
                delivery=Integer.parseInt(delivertime.getText().toString());
                feed=Integer.parseInt(feedrate.getText().toString());
                seller=Integer.parseInt(sellerrate.getText().toString());

                (new postmanager()).execute();
                //zeeed 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

    adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    if (list != null) {
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    adapter1 = new C1Adapter();
    if (list1 != null) {
        c1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }
    adapter2 = new C1Adapter();
    if (list1 != null) {
        c2.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }
    adapter3 = new C1Adapter();
    if (list1 != null) {
        c3.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }

    //List category
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scategory=list.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Scategory, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}); 
    // List Primary color
    c1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Pcolor=list1.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Pcolor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }); 
    // List secondery color
    c2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scolor=list2.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Scolor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }); 
    // List third color
    c3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Tcolor=list3.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Tcolor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }); 


    //end of onCreate

}



    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(Userfilter.this, R.layout.filter, list);


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
System.out.println("in adapter");
            // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.filtertv, parent, false);
                System.out
                        .println("+____________________________________________+");
            }

            String currentitem = list.get(position);

TextView category=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.filtertv);

category.setText(currentitem);

            // Fill the view

                        return itemView;
        }

    }
    private class C1Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public C1Adapter() {
            super(Userfilter.this, R.layout.color, list1);


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
System.out.println("in adapter");
            // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View colorView = convertView;
            if (colorView == null) {
                colorView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.color, parent, false);
                System.out
                        .println("+____________________________________________+");
            }

            String currentcolor = list1.get(position);

TextView color=(TextView)colorView.findViewById(R.id.colortv);

color.setText(currentcolor);

            // Fill the view

                        return colorView;
        }
    }
        private class C2Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            public C2Adapter() {
                super(Userfilter.this, R.layout.color, list2);


            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("in adapter");
                // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
                View colorView = convertView;
                if (colorView == null) {
                    colorView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.color, parent, false);
                    System.out
                            .println("+____________________________________________+");
                }

                String currentcolor = list1.get(position);

    TextView color=(TextView)colorView.findViewById(R.id.colortv);

    color.setText(currentcolor);

                // Fill the view

                            return colorView;
            }



    }




                public class postmanager extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
            @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userID));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", Scategory));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("minprice", Smin));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("maxprice", Smax));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pcolor", Pcolor));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Scolor", Scolor));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tcolor", Tcolor));

                // checkboxes w ints

        //zeed

                System.out.println("addded all params");

                try {
                    System.out.println(" url:  " + url1);

                    System.out.println("khoder");
                    JSONObject json =jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url1, "POST", params);
                    Log.d("Create response",json.toString());

                    json.getString("success");  





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                        return true;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

                        if (success) {                                  
                            }}}}
```

Another question how to send params of checkboxes and integers. thank you

Comment: Please try to narrow your code down to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` in your xml for your checkbox `secondHand`. And you do not have this method in your Activity code.

Comment: public int onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
            }

Comment: is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes add that and see if it stops crashing

Comment: Or remove that from xml  and add secondHand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public int onCheckboxClicked(View view) {...

Comment: secondhand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public int onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        switch(view.getId()) {
     case R.id.checkbox_secondhand:
                if (checked)
                   return 1;
                else
                   return 0;
        }
     return 0;
    } 
   }); 
But an error under View.onClickListener 
The type new View.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)

Comment: Rename onCheckboxClicked to onClick